# How to release memory as using UITableViewController

Tags: iphone

I'm using Instruments to monitor memory usage. I notice that memory always increase and not release anymore on my UITableViewController. I don't understand why. Following I list my codes

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int row =  [indexPath section];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ApplicationCell";
    BookCell *cell = (BookCell *)[tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BookCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = bookCell;
        self.bookCell=nil;
    }   
    Book *book = [books objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.bookNameLabel.text = book.author;  
    cell.bookPriceLabel.text = book.price;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is Instruments telling you is not released? Usually it will tell you what class is not being released, as well as where in the call stack.

Comment: I solved this issue. I forgot release some elements in my own custom CellView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hie...

Just try it this way, i hope i would work

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  int row =  [indexPath section];

  if(cell == nil) {
      [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BookCell" owner:self options:nil];
      cell = bookCell;
      self.bookCell=nil;
  }
  Book *book = [books objectAtIndex:row];
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
  cell.bookNameLabel.text = book.author;
  cell.bookPriceLabel.text = book.price;
  cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
      return cell;
  }

Answer (score 0):

**Answer #1:**

If you are referring to memory allocation and not leaking memory, here is a suggestion.

Implement **viewDidUnload** to release parts of your viewcontroller that are no longer needed.  Typically, you would re-instantate these objects in **viewDidLoad** (or **loadView** if you are not using xib files).

You can visualize this by placing NSLog statements inside **viewDidUnload** and in iphone simulator and click "Hardware->Simulate Memory Warning",  unless they already unloaded, most of your non-visible viewcontrollers will run the **viewdidunload** method.

**Answer #2:**

If you are referring to memory leaks, then I would suspect the way you are loading table cells is leaking memory.  [Here is a good reference for loading tablecells from xibs](http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/06/28/custom-uitableviewcell-from-a-xib-in-interface-builder/).  Your method might be correct, I'm just not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks leak-free to me.

I also noticed that the following line looks like it should be causing release of your custom cell object early (assuming the bookCell property is declared as "retain"):

```
self.bookCell=nil;
```

I would recommend removing it completely. You could also change it to (assuming the instance variable name matches the property name):

```
bookCell=nil;
```